# Returning a vector element

Tags: c++, vector, return-type

I have a vector containing objects of type FieldBase. I'm trying to search for a FieldBase element with a specific name and return it.

I'm getting the error:

> error C2664: 'FieldBase::FieldBase(const FieldBase &)' : cannot
>   convert parameter 1 from 'FieldBase *' to 'const FieldBase &' 1>
>   Reason: cannot convert from 'FieldBase *' to 'const FieldBase' 1>
>   No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload
>   resolution was ambiguous

Here is my `FieldBase` class

```
class FieldBase {
    public:
        FieldBase();

        CString name;
        bool state;
        int size;

        CString getName();
        void setName(CString name);
        bool getState();
        void setState(bool state);
        int getSize();
        void setSize(int size);
};
```

This is the method that is trying to return the object:

```
FieldBase GetField(CString name) {
    vector<FieldBase*>::iterator it;
    for (it = m_Message.begin(); it != m_Message.end(); ++it) {
        if (name.Compare((*it)->getName()) == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return *it;
}
```

Perhaps another question worth asking is how come `(*it)->getName()` doesn't give a compilation error but return `*it` does?

Comment: Because `*it` is a pointer, not a value.

Comment: Perhaps because 'it' is on the stack and can't be passed back as a result to a calling function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You vector contains pointers, you are returning *it which is a pointer, but your signature returns an object.

Use:

```
return **it;
```

Except if there is no match!

Better to return the iterator

```
vector<FieldBase*>::iterator GetField( ....

...

return it;
}
```

In the long run, you would be best to learn how to use std::find()

Comment: `return **it` worked and did what I wanted. Using `return it` gave the following error intead: `error C2664: 'FieldBase::FieldBase(const FieldBase &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>' to 'const FieldBase &'`

Comment: As I showed in my answer, if you want to return the iterator ( which is better ) then you have to change the method signature.  Note that returning the object will cause a horrible crash if the string you are searching for is NOT present in the vector.